# Unable to use Emgucv CUDA

Tags: c#

Does anyone know why I am unable to use CUDA, I have a Nvidia graphics card installed that has CUDA enabled, specifically a GTX 660, and I also have the CUDA driver and toolkit installed. However, when I try to use "HasCuda" function, it always returns false. Also when I try to compile a program without checking for CUDA, I just get an error. So does anyone have any instructions on how to properly install Emgucv with CUDA in Visual Studio 2015, by the way, I got Emgucv from the nuget package.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV.Cuda;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void CUDACheck()
        {
            if (CudaInvoke.HasCuda)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("CUDA On");
           }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("CUDA Off");
           }
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           CUDACheck();
       }
   }
}
```

The result is always "Cuda Off".

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are using a build of Emgu that was not built with CUDA enabled. The build without CUDA enabled is more commonly used since it is a much smaller package. I was using the package from NuGet myself, which seems to be without CUDA enabled. You will have to make sure you are using a build with -cuda in it's name, which you will probably have to download from SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv. Go to Files, and find the file you need.

Comment: It seems like the problem, but I need to add the entire packages with cuda support.

Answer (score 2):

Downloade the executables with `xxx_cuda_xxx` from here: [Emgucv sourceforge executables](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/3.3/). Remove the one you installed from nuGet package manager. Add reference to the package bin folder from where you downloaded and installed. Manually copy the `concrt140.dll`, `cvextern.dll`, `msvcp140.dll`, `opencv_ffmepg330_64.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` into your debug or release folder. Then it should let you to use cuda, for more version compatible info, please refer to: [Emgucv Version History](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History). The reason why the one that you downloaded from nuGet package manager didn't work is simply because that version didn't support GPU computations.